# Why aren't fasteners open standards?

Tags: fasteners, standards

I just wanted to find information for an M2 flat head hex socket machine screw which, I believe, is defined by ISO 10642, but unfortunately that is locked behind a paywall of a couple hundred dollars. Unless an individual has money to throw around, that information is out of their grasp, and that doesn't seem entirely fair to me. So I was just wondering the reasoning behind why its chosen to make that sort of general information a closed standard.

Comment: Paid for as people don't work for free...

Comment: Actually ASTM committee members are paid by employers , not ASTM. But as an organizer/manager/publisher , etc, ASTM does charge for standards to cover costs. API and ASME are the same.

Comment: So, from the organizations' perspective, all specifications and standards are produce by volunteers.

Comment: Some irony; the people who write the standards must also buy them from the organization. Except API does give speciations to the committee members.

Comment: A couple hundred dollars is peanuts for any serious user of this information. It is definitely unfortunate that DIYers can't pay a DIY-appropriate price for standards. It's a failure of our economic system that applies in lots of cases (e.g. students pirating software)

Answer (score 1):

A google search brings this page with useful charts, and data.

[image: screen capture]

[ISO 10642](https://www.fasteners.eu/standards/ISO/10642/)